# Geometric interpretation of analyticity?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, intuition

> Suppose the real valued functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are continuous and have continuous first order partial derivatives in a domain $D$. If $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations at all points of $D$, then the complex function $f(z)= u+iv$ is analytic in $D$.

Could someone please give me a geometric interpretation of the theorem above?

The Cauchy Riemann equations can be interpreted as saying the the gradient of $u$ and $v$ must be perpendicular for the function to be differentiable.

Comment: The creation of such theorems has not arisen from intuition, but pure algebraic work !
Ofcourse it's possible for it to have such a interpretation !

Comment: @FardadPouran Yes, but I don't really find the algebraic derivation satisfying. Geometric interpretations help me understand the concept on a much deeper level.

Comment: It's more easy for a wide concept or a wide field in mathematics to be fit in our intuition, but it's far to interpret just one theorem .
For example you can find an intuition of generality of Complex Analysis, but I don't think this theorem and theorems like this could be interpreted !
Specially as you see this theorem's condition are even technical and not intuitive !

Comment: In addition, the intuition over Complex Analysis is not completely Geometric !
$$$$
You can just have a good feeling of understanding and cognition of whole world of complex spaces and functions !

Comment: You can probably get an answer in the book " Visual Complex Analysis " by Tristan Needham.

Comment: These may be old answers but I want to say that I believe your opinion is very naive, Fardad. Many theorems have deeper meanings (for instance geometric ones) - especially in Complex Analysis, a highly intuitive subject. Even if these insights may not seem obvious at first, one should still always strive to find an interpretation because only then do you truly understand the theorem/object/... Sometimes, you can give intuitive (!) explanations to why a geometric interpretation would be difficult. However, I don‘t agree with yours, the conditions are not technical. That‘s all I wanted to say.

Answer (score 3):

A more elegant statement of the same theorem would be to say:

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb C$ be a function. Then $f$ is holomorphic if any only if the best linear approximation for $f(z)$ about a point $z_0$ can be written as, for some $c\in\mathbb C$:
>   $$f(z_0)+c(z-z_0).$$

Note that when we say "linear approximation" we mean "linear over $\mathbb R$" - for instance a function like
$$f(x+iy)=x+iy^2$$
is not holomorphic because near $z_0=0$, we can compute the best linear approximation of $f(x+iy)$ as $x$, since the derivative of $y^2$ with respect to $y$ (or $x$) is $0$ there. However, there is no $c$ such that $x=c(x+iy)$, contradicting hypothesis. This means that, near $0$, $f$ is acting like the projection of $(x+iy)$ onto the real axis.

However, a function like
$$f(x+iy)=(x+iy)^2=x^2-y^2+2xyi$$
has, near any point $z_0=x_0+iy_0$ that we can approximate
$$f(x+iy)\approx f(z_0) + 2x_0(x-x_0)-2y_0(y-y_0)+(2x_0(y-y_0)+2y_0(x-x_0))i$$
where we can rewrite the left-hand side, after grouping terms and thinking a bit as
$$f(x+iy)\approx f(z_0) + (2x_0+2iy_0)((x+iy)-(x_0+iy_0))$$
$$f(z)\approx f(z_0) + 2z_0(z-z_0)$$
which is of the desired form. However, a function like $f(z_0)+c(z-z_0)$ has a nice interpretation: It is a [spiral similarity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpiralSimilarity.html) centered at $z_0$ which rotates by $\arg(c)$ and scales by $|c|$. This excludes the possibility $f$ could act like a projection, as it did in the non-holomorphic example. (Notice that $c=f'(z_0)$, so this gives a precise geometric meaning to the argument and modulus of the derivative at a point)

So, a really simple geometric interpretation is:

> $f$ is holomorphic if and only if the best linear approximation for $f$ about any point is a spiral similarity.

We can get a bit deeper than this though. Notice that any spiral similarity preserves angles. Therefore, so long as $f'(z_0)$ is not zero at a point, near the point $z_0$, the function $f$ will act like a particular spiral similarity and will therefore preserve any angle with vertex at $z_0$. If $f'(z_0)$ is nowhere zero, then this means that $f$ is angle preserving - that is, if we drew any figure on $\mathbb C$, then looked at its image, the angles of the figure in the image would be equal to those in the original. We call a map "conformal" if it has this property of preserving angles which gives the interpretation:

> If $f$ is a conformal map $\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$, then it is holomorphic.

and, more generally, since $f$ might not be conformal where $f'(z_0)=0$ - for instance, drawing a right angle at $0$ on the complex plane by drawing a path along the points $i$ then $0$ then $1$ then applying the holomorphic map $z\mapsto z^2$ gives the image as a path from $-1$ to $0$ to $1$, with an angle of $\pi$ - twice the original angle. (This is related to why [Cauchy's integral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) works).

Comment: Thank you! Couple of questions though. You say: "It is a spiral similarity centered at $z_0$   which rotates by $arg(c)$  and scales by $|c|$". But then you also say that if the function acts like a spiral symmetry, its angle preserving. How can it be angle preserving and rotate by $arg(c)$ at the same time?

Comment: Rotations are angle-preserving - "angle-preserving" means that the image of an angle is the same angle, not that the image of a line has the same angle to a reference line. That is, for instance, the map $f(z)=iz$ is a rotation of the complex plane by a right angle, and it takes a right angle formed by the path $i$ to $0$ to $1$ and maps to to a path $-1$ to $0$ to $i$, which is still a right angle - the figure has been rotated, but its angle has not changed measure.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. 

I'm having trouble seeing how you got from the second last theorem to the last one. How does continuity handle the case where $f'(z_0) = 0$ and $f$ is therefore non-conformal?

Comment: Upon further reflection, I'm not sure that that's true (though it might be), so I took that out. I suppose you could just go for "at $x$ where $f$ is not conformal, the term $f(x+\delta)-f(x)$ must be of order $O(\delta^2)$ - that is, the best linear approximation there must be a constant function" - which is equivalent to demanding that $f'(z_0)=0$ where $f$ is not conformal.

Comment: How does that relate to continuity though?

Comment: Well, a holomorphic function certainly has to be continuous

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the continuity of the first partial derivatives.

Comment: Well, the main thing with continuous first partial derivatives is that, if you don't have that, then it's not really meaningful what is meant by the measurement of an angle in the image - if we don't have continuous partial derivatives, then we could be mapping polygons to fractals - and this wouldn't be a "conformal" map because we wouldn't even have a meaningful definition of the measure of an angle in our image. I suppose "conformal almost everywhere, and mapping smooth curves to smooth curves" would suffice to establish holomorphic too.

Comment: I'm sorry but that comment was completely above my head.  If the partial derivatives are not continuous on some region, but exist at every point, and the Cauchy Riemann equations are met at every point, the best linear approximation at every point would be a rotation and and a scaling. So shouldn't the conditions be that the partial derivatives are defined at every point in the region and the Cauchy Riemann equations are met?

Comment: Not quite; an explicit counterexample is $f(z)=e^{-z^{-4}}$ (with $f(0)=0$), which has partial derivatives everywhere, since, for real $x$ the functions $f(x)$ and $f(ix)$ behave nicely - but $f$ isn't continuous near $0$ (approaching by $f(x+2ix)$ shows that the discontinuity is actually very nasty - certainly $f$ is nothing like a rotation & scaling near $0$). However, "$f$ is continuous, and satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equations everywhere" is, indeed, sufficient (this is the [Looman-Menchoff theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem)).

Comment: I see that that argument fails for your counterargument but I still don't understand why the continuity of the partial derivatives are required. Going back to your previous comment, you said " if we don't have continuous partial derivatives, then we could be mapping polygons to fractals - and this wouldn't be a "conformal" map because we wouldn't even have a meaningful definition of the measure of an angle in our image". Could you please expand on what you meant by that? Why wouldn't you have a meaningful measure of an angle? The image still exists right?